# Перегрузка операторов в классе множеств

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь, надо реализовать класс с множествами и реализовать для них сложение и вычитание, проблема заключается в том что я не могу вывести результаты

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class NewClass
{
  public:
    int *p;
    short int _size;
  public:
    NewClass(int A) :_size(A) // NewClass P(5);
    {
      p = new int[_size];
      for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
        p[i] = rand() % 10;

    };
    NewClass(int *p1) { p = p1; }; // int A[5]{1,2,3,4,5} ; NewClass Mas(A); 
    NewClass() {};

    NewClass operator +(NewClass& value)
    {
      int size1 = _size;
      NewClass mas;
      for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i)
      {
        if (p[i] == value.p[i])
        {
          value.p[i] = value.p[i + 1];
          size1--;
        }
      }
      mas = new int[size1 + _size];
      for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i) mas.p[i] = p[i];
      for (int i = _size; i < (_size + size1); ++i) mas.p[i] = value.p[i];

      return mas;
   }

   NewClass operator -(NewClass& value)
   {
     int size1 = _size, size2 = _size;
     for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
     {
       if (p[i] == value.p[i])
         {
           value.p[i] = value.p[i + 1];
           p[i] = p[i + 1];
           size1--;
           size2--;
         }
    }
    NewClass mas;
    mas = new int[size1 + _size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; ++i) mas.p[i] = p[i];
    for (int i = size2; i < (size2 + size1); ++i) mas.p[i] = value.p[i];

    return mas;
  }

  void show()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
    {
      std::cout << p[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
  };

};

int main() 
{
  int _size;
  cin >> _size;
  srand(time(0));
  NewClass A(_size);
  NewClass B(_size);
  NewClass C();
  A.show();
  B.show();
  int k;
  cout << "Enter 1 to sum or 2 to diff -> ";
  cin >> k;

  if (k == 1)
  A + B;
  if (k == 2)
  A - B;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Давно не видел столь ужасного, неграмотного кода. К вам множество претензий. я пытался запустить его у себя, но понимаю, что довести его до ума можно только полностью переписав. Как он вообще скомпилировался ?
Рекомендации вам:

1. Выравнивайте код, следите за стилем, читать ваш код ужасная мука. Называйте переменные как можно информативнее.
2. В циклах вместо `i++` используйте `++i`.
3. Явно разделите объявление и определение функции. А если, всё же по каким-то причинам не хотите, хотя бы не ставьте лишние `;` после квадратных скобок. Это может привести к неопределённому результату в случае компиляции.
4. Почти везде вы выделяете память для `*p`, но нигде не освобождаете. Следите за вашей памятью, выделяйте и уничтожайте её когда нужно, я даже тут не вижу деструктора.
5. Не используйте циклы для копирования данных между указателями, есть замечательная функция `memcpy`
6. Для вашего класса НОРМАЛЬНО объявите все нужные конструкторы, операторы. Вы используете оператор присвоения, но он явно нигде не объявлён.
7. В конструкторах копируйте данные в ваш класс, а не просто присваивайте указатели.
8. Для переноса строки в `std::cout` используйте `std::endl`. В интернете можете найти информацию почему.
9. Делайте ваши классы универсальными, шаблонными.
10. Уберите из тела класса функцию `show`, она нарушает принципы ООП проектирования.

Вам ещё рано писать собственные классы.